# How do I extract the first argument from a function in tree-sitter

Tags: typescript, treesitter

Given that I have the code below in JavaScript/Typescript:

```js
findOne('testing', () => {
});

findLegacy('testing2', () => {
});

findOne('testing3', () => {
});
```

I want to match the first argument of every function call using a tree-sitter query.

Here's where I got to, it matches *all* arguments

```scm
(call_expression arguments: (arguments) @arguments)
```

How do I match only the *first* argument?

As a bonus challenge, can I match the first argument of functions called `findOne` only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I match only the first argument?

```scm
(call_expression
  arguments: (arguments ((string)+ @desc))
)
```

> As a bonus challenge, can I match the first argument of functions called findOne only?

Yes. See Predicates section in the query syntax docs: https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/using-parsers#query-syntax

```scm
(call_expression
  function: (identifier) @fn
  arguments: (arguments ((string)+ @desc))
  (#eq? @fn "findOne")
)
```